# ¿Cómo puedo leer un texto y determinar: si tiene más de 10 caracteres, eliminar esos caracteres?

Tags: python

Trato de llamar a un archivo **A**, leer línea por línea y determinar si esa línea tiene una longitud, digamos que, de 10 caracteres, si esa línea tiene una longitud mayor, se omita y pase a la siguiente línea. En caso de que este cumpla con la condición, se guarde en el archivo **B**.
Algo así:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\youna\Desktop\Combinaciones_AABB.txt") as codigos:
    newcodes = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in codigos]

archivo=open('Menor_diez.txt', 'w')

for line in newcodes:
    if line < len(10):
        archivo.write(f'{line}')    
archivo.close()
```

Pero no sé como implementar en la condición, el saber cuál es la longitud de la línea.
¿Cómo puedo corregir esto?
De antemano muchas gracias y saludos!

Comment: La función `len()` te da la longitud de una _secuencia_. Úsala para saber la longitud de la línea: `len(line)`. Lo que no tiene ningún sentido es que la apliques a un entero (`len(10)`).

Comment: Entonces ¿cómo determino la longitud de 10 de cada línea?,    `str(len(line))`, no me dice nada, faltaría determinar la condicional y declarar la longitud de 10. Justamente esa es la duda que tengo :/

Comment: Ok era al revés, ya entendí: `len(line) < 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución: la función `traspasa` recibe los nombre de un archivo de entrada, uno de salida y el largo a seleccionar, traspasando al archivo de salida todas las líneas de la entrada menores al largo dado:

```
def traspasa(entrada, salida, largo):
    with open(entrada, "rt") as arch_in:
        with open(salida, "wt") as arch_out:
            for line in arch_in:
                if len(line) < 10:
                    arch_out.write(line)
```

Luego de abrir los archivos, recorre la entrada. Si el largo de la línea (incluyendo el `\n`) es menor a 10, la graba en la salida.

Para saber la longitud de una cadena o el número de elementos en una lista, tupla, etc, basta con usar la función `len`, pasando como parámetro aquello que se quiere medir.

**Demo**

El código completo, selecciona las líneas cortas del Quijote:

```
def traspasa(entrada, salida, largo):
    with open(entrada, "rt") as arch_in:
        with open(salida, "wt") as arch_out:
            for line in arch_in:
                if len(line) < 10:
                    arch_out.write(line)

traspasa("quijote.txt", "cortas.txt", 10)
```

Nota: la pregunta es confusa. En una parte dice eliminar las menores a 10 y en otra las más largas. Hay que decidirse por una y cambiar el `if` acorde. Actualmente graba líneas menores a 10.

Comment: Muchas gracias Candi Moe, prácticamente era `len(line) < 10` y no `line < len(10)`, porque lo estoy interpretando como entero.